# Cross validation Deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, deep-learning

[image]

$$f_{i}=A(D/ D_{i})$$
$$e_{j}=L(f_{i}, z^{(j)})$$

It seems to me, that above definition of k-folded cross validation algorithm (from Deep Learning book by Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville, 2016) is inconsistent with the common definition of cross - validation. In above algorithm $e$ vector is the vector of **loss function** calculated for every particular example in the $D$ dataset, and then mean of vector $e$ is the estimation of generalization error. Whereas in standard definition of cross - validation, we calculate test error for each fold and then calculate average of them.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the difference between those two definitions of cross validation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's really no distinction between those definitions. (Perspective, perhaps?) As the pictured text reads, emphasis mine:

> The algorithm returns the vector of errors $\epsilon$ for each example in $\mathbb{D}$, **whose mean is the estimated generalization error**.

To square this with the definition you give above, note that the mean of all errors is equal to the weighted (by $\frac{|\mathbb{D_i}|}{N}$) average of means over each of k folds. (K-fold cross validation error is a weighted average of errors of particular folds.)

Comment: "note that the mean of all errors is equal to the weighted (by |Di||Di|) average of means over each of k folds.". Could you provide derivation?

Comment: Sorry, I goofed that formula twice—should now follow from expressing each group mean as $\Sigma_{\mathbb{D}_i}\epsilon_j$.

Comment: My misconception was a result of assumption that cross validation error is a non - weighted average of errors of particular folds, wheareas cross validation is a weighted average, which is often not highlighted in textbooks.

Comment: Often times texts will sort of hand-wave over the assumption that each of the k folds are of equal size (making the two equivalent). Will jot up an edit shortly.